# You are trying to add a non-nullable field 'password' to user without a default

Tags: django, django-models

I am building a Django project in Docker Environment using below Docker YAML file:

```
django_3.2.4:
    build:
      context: ./ImageBuild/
      dockerfile: Dockerfile_Build_Django
    container_name: Django_3.2.4
    depends_on: 
      - Postgres_13.2
    environment:
      - DJANGO_SUPERUSER_USERNAME=admin
      - DJANGO_SUPERUSER_PASSWORD=123456
      - DJANGO_SUPERUSER_EMAIL=admin@abc.com
    networks:
      external_net:
        ipv4_address: 192.168.100.22
    restart: always
    volumes: 
      - ./IoTSite/:/usr/src/app/
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro

    command: sh -c "python manage.py makemigrations && python manage.py migrate && python manage.py createsuperuser --noinput --no-input && rsync --daemon && gunicorn"
```

And I created a Custom User Model as below: (with AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'IoTSite.User' added in settings.py)

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    UserID = models.CharField('username：',help_text='required', max_length=20, primary_key=True,unique=True, blank=False)
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'UserID'
    First_Name = models.CharField('first_name：',max_length = 2)
    Last_Name = models.CharField('last_name：',max_length = 2)
    Date_Created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, editable=False)  #timestamps for creation, hidden from user input
    Date_Birth = models.DateField('Birthday：')
    Gender_Choice = [
        ('Male','Male'),
        ('Female','Female'),
    ]
    Gender = models.CharField('Gender：',choices=Gender_Choice, max_length=1)
```

**When I run the container by command `docker-compose up`, it failed with below error: (and container keeps on restarting, I did not have opportunity to key in my selection)**

```
2021-06-15T03:17:32.964281763Z WARNINGS:
2021-06-15T03:17:32.964284245Z IoTSite.Category: (models.W042) Auto-created primary key used when not defining a primary key type, by default 'django.db.models.AutoField'.
2021-06-15T03:17:32.964287706Z  HINT: Configure the DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD setting or the IoTSiteConfig.default_auto_field attribute to point to a subclass of AutoField, e.g. 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'.
2021-06-15T03:17:32.964300827Z IoTSite.Tag: (models.W042) Auto-created primary key used when not defining a primary key type, by default 'django.db.models.AutoField'.
2021-06-15T03:17:32.964303505Z  HINT: Configure the DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD setting or the IoTSiteConfig.default_auto_field attribute to point to a subclass of AutoField, e.g. 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'.
2021-06-15T03:17:32.964252008Z You are trying to add a non-nullable field 'password' to user without a default; we can't do that (the database needs something to populate existing rows).
2021-06-15T03:17:32.964327053Z Please select a fix:
2021-06-15T03:17:32.964329519Z  1) Provide a one-off default now (will be set on all existing rows with a null value for this column)
2021-06-15T03:17:32.964331734Z  2) Quit, and let me add a default in models.py
2021-06-15T03:17:32.966604773Z Traceback (most recent call last):
2021-06-15T03:17:32.966623599Z   File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
2021-06-15T03:17:32.966628470Z     main()
2021-06-15T03:17:32.966632261Z   File "manage.py", line 17, in main
2021-06-15T03:17:32.966635587Z     execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
2021-06-15T03:17:32.966645274Z   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 419, in execute_from_command_line
2021-06-15T03:17:32.966648823Z     utility.execute()
2021-06-15T03:17:32.966651673Z   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 413, in execute
2021-06-15T03:17:32.966654967Z     self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
2021-06-15T03:17:32.966658158Z   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 354, in run_from_argv
2021-06-15T03:17:32.966661881Z     self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
2021-06-15T03:17:32.966665276Z   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 398, in execute
2021-06-15T03:17:32.966668279Z     output = self.handle(*args, **options)
2021-06-15T03:17:32.966670415Z   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 89, in wrapped
2021-06-15T03:17:32.966672767Z     res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
2021-06-15T03:17:32.966675010Z   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/makemigrations.py", line 176, in handle
2021-06-15T03:17:32.966677391Z     migration_name=self.migration_name,
2021-06-15T03:17:32.966679496Z   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/autodetector.py", line 41, in changes
2021-06-15T03:17:32.966681780Z     changes = self._detect_changes(convert_apps, graph)
2021-06-15T03:17:32.966683889Z   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/autodetector.py", line 183, in _detect_changes
2021-06-15T03:17:32.966686197Z     self.generate_added_fields()
2021-06-15T03:17:32.966688301Z   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/autodetector.py", line 859, in generate_added_fields
2021-06-15T03:17:32.966690981Z     self._generate_added_field(app_label, model_name, field_name)
2021-06-15T03:17:32.966693174Z   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/autodetector.py", line 880, in _generate_added_field
2021-06-15T03:17:32.966695472Z     field.default = self.questioner.ask_not_null_addition(field_name, model_name)
2021-06-15T03:17:32.966697647Z   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/questioner.py", line 153, in ask_not_null_addition
2021-06-15T03:17:32.966708157Z     "Quit, and let me add a default in models.py",
2021-06-15T03:17:32.966710562Z   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/questioner.py", line 98, in _choice_input
2021-06-15T03:17:32.966713409Z     result = input("Select an option: ")
2021-06-15T03:17:32.966715649Z EOFError: EOF when reading a line
2021-06-15T03:17:33.178780079Z Select an option: 2021-06-15T03:17:35.570587292Z You are trying to add a non-nullable field 'password' to user without a default; we can't do that (the database needs something to populate existing rows).
```

**Q1: How should I fix above error please ?**

**Edits:** I reviewed the source code,
django.contribs.auth.base_user.py

```
class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
    password = models.CharField(_('password'), max_length=128)
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(_('last login'), blank=True, null=True)

    is_active = True

    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []
```

And django.contribs.auth.models.py

```
class AbstractUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    EMAIL_FIELD = 'email'
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['email']
```

**Q2: How come default value for filed `password` is required when creating tables (not real users yet) in DB during makemigrations?**

Comment: Is your `User` model new? You need to run `makemigrations` in a separate process so that you can provide input: `docker-compose run --rm django_3.2.4 python manage.py makemigrations`

Comment: yes, it is newly created model. if there a way to avoid running `makemigrations` in a separate process? or this is the only option ?

Comment: If it's a newly created model you shouldn't be asked to provide defaults, maybe something messed up with your applications? You will need to run `makemigrations` separately many times for this exact circumstance, yes

Comment: I deleted those `makemigrations` , `migrate` and `createsuperuser` commands in docker YAML file. Then re-created the container, and  ran `makemigrations` manually on CLI of Django Container, still got this error. `You are trying to add a non-nullable field 'password' to user without a default`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the custom Model class name from `class User(AbstractUser):` to `class Employee(AbstractUser):` solves the problem.  I have no idea why, perhaps because this change avoids duplication of Model class name (there is another django built-in model class also named **"User"**)

```
//django.contrib.auth.models.py
class User(AbstractUser):
```